# MSG.EXE not found, but it's there?

Tags: c#, process.start

I'm having some trouble understanding why my C# process.start doesn't work. The code is listed below, and I have verified that the msg.exe is in the C:\Windows\System32\ folder. I can use the command from a batch file just fine, or from the command line. I cannot get it to work in my C# code for some reason. I do have "using System.Diagnostics" added, and this is Windows 10 Pro. The error is "The system cannot find the file specified." Any help would be great. Thank you!

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string mypath = @"C:\Windows\System32\";
    Process.Start(@mypath + "msg.exe " + " * /time:20 hello there");
}
```

I have also used this, but it didn't work either:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\msg.exe * /time:20 hello there");
}
```

Comment: Process.start with 2 args...second is the command line arguments

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your file request is being redirected because you are trying to open a 64-bit path from a 32-bit application.

You are asking for:

```
C:\Windows\System32\msg.exe
```

Windows is actually searching for this, though:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msg.exe
```

What you need to use, instead, to ensure that the file will be looked for under `System32`, is this:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\Sysnative\msg.exe", "* /time:20 hello there");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this as you suggested, but I'm still receiving that same error, The system cannot find the file specified. Perhaps I have a setting wrong somewhere? I'm totally confused on why this isn't working. Thanks.

Comment: @SandraTinch See my edit. I forgot to put the comma between the parameters.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. This has about driven me insane! Thank you again.